# Does there exist a function such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^{\star} } t^nf(t)dt=0$?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, integration

Let $f\in C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ such that $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} t^nf(t)dt=0$ for all integer n.

We know that $f\equiv 0$. It's call **Hausdorff theorem**.

- This theorem is wrong on $\mathbb{R^+}$, a counter example is :
  $$f(x)=\exp(-x^{\frac{1}{4}})\sin(x^\frac{1}{4})$$

> In fact this exercice was posted in MSE and actually I don't understand how someone can construct a such example ? Can we find it by ourselves ?
>   Is there exist some reference of this theorem (History perhaps..) ?

**Reference**

1. [The exercise in Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689218/does-there-exist-a-function-such-that-int-mathbbr-star-tnftdt-0)

Thank you in advance for your time,

Julien.

Comment: See **Fourier Analysis** by T. W. Körner.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thank you but 80$ for a book is a bit expensive ..

Comment: @NeilHoffman What is your $k$ ? I did not really understand everything. Can you elaborate a little more please ?

Comment: Perhaps I missing an implied assumption, but I think this works. Consider a function $g_0(t)=\{0 \mbox{ on } [0,1], 1/k \mbox{ on } [2k-1,2k], -1/k \mbox{ on } (2k,2k+1)\}$. Let $g_1(t)$ be a continuous function that approximates $g_0(t)$ such that $g_1(t)$ also has the property that $\int_{x=2k} ^{2k+2} g_1(t)dt=0$. Now, let $f(t)=g_1(t)/t^n$ if $t\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I just cleaned the comment up a little, so hopefully its more readable. $k$ is the floor of (t+1)/2.

Comment: The key words to look up in indexes of books, or online, are "Hamburger moment problem". But I don't understand what your question is, exactly: do you need someone to explain the example on MSE (in which case, take this question to MSE) or do you want to know the history of such examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard reference is N. I.  Akhiezer, The Classical moment problem and some related questions of analysis, MR0184042.

There is also a paper:
MR1627806 Simon, Barry The classical moment problem as a self-adjoint finite difference operator. Adv. Math. 137 (1998), no. 1, 82–203.

Comment: Available [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/akhiezer.pdf).

Comment: I didn't know this reference. Thank you.

Comment: Andres, thanks for the reference:-) I did not know about the free English translation. Almost all Russian (Soviet) books are available free.